# How do you use sed to remove up to a certain key in a very large json file?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to remove up to a certain element defined by KEYNAME in a very large json file.

`sed 's/^.* KEYNAME/KEYNAME' metadata_unique_all.json`

Tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

specifically, for example, the .json file contains millions of rows that look similar to this but with a unique name key:

```
 {
        "name": "assets/KEYNAME",
        "displayName": "random display name",
        "authorName": "Some Guy"
 }
```

Comment: you'd be better of manipulating JSON with something that can parse JSON - eg, `jq` ... *jq is like sed for JSON data*

Comment: ah looking into jq - thanks! ... also trying to learn sed, trying to understand why replace string above does not work

Comment: @ina sed is a bad tool for handling JSON, but if you want to know why that didn't work, we will need to see an example of your input as well. What did you expect to happen and what actually happened? Please [edit] and add the example and also clarify what you are asking: is this about how to parse JSON on the command line (not sed), or is it about why this sed command didn't work as expected? Oh, and that command would give a syntax error, so it's probably been copied wrong. Please edit and  show us the actual command you used.

Comment: updated with a more verbose input. basically associative key

Comment: your replacement will break the JSON, clearly

Comment: (1) Your `sed` lacks the closing `/` of the `s` command (`s/pattern/substitute/`). (2) Your pattern contains a whitespace before `KEYNAME`, while the example has a slash before it, so it won't match. (3) If it would match, it would remove everything before `KEYNAME`, so the line would be `KEYNAME",` which is certainly not what you want.